# How can I create a tuple consisting of class objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

This question is for Python version 2.7. For example, if I have the following class:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
object = Example("x", "y")
t = tuple(object)
```

After executing the code above I get `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence` because I can only store a single variable of the object inside the tuple and not the object itself. My question is, is there an easy solution to store class objects in tuples such that `tuple = (o1, o2, o3)` where `o1, o2 and o3` are objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to call `tuple` on the object to do this:

```
obj = Example("x", "y")
t = (obj,) # one item tuple
```

Be careful to not use the name `object` to not shadow the builtin `object` class.

To create a tuple with more than one item:

```
t = (obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

Note that the *parenthesis* serve only for grouping and removing them will not have any effect.

Comment: Yes! This seems to work. To access class variables all I have to do is `t[0].a` for example.

Comment: @Sajid Yes, you can access them like so

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't really have to do with the type of the tuple's elements, but rather with single-item tuples. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses).

Note the following:

```
In [1]: a = (1)

In [2]: type(a)
Out[2]: int

In [3]: a = (1, )

In [4]: type(a)
Out[4]: tuple

In [5]: a = 1, 

In [6]: type(a)
Out[6]: tuple
```

Comment: This was not really the problem I had, but this is good information!

Comment: @Sajid :-) padding